# Using USB controller for keyboard input (APC40 --> WoW)

Tags: keyboard, mapping, usb, midi

I'm looking to do something pretty specific, but it's got a more general application.

Specifically, I happen to own an [APC40 controller](http://www.akaipro.com/apc40), which is a giant grid of buttons, used for making electronic music (triggering samples, etc.).

I'd love to be able to use this massive grid of buttons that the APC40 provides as a video game controller, specifically as a way to trigger spells in WoW, a game which requires seemingly 3x as many keys as exist on a keyboard.

Yes I am that nerdy.

The question is, how can I do it?  I'd love to translate or map the APC40's button pushes to keystrokes, and then WoW won't notice the difference.

Any way to get my Mac OS X laptop to map input from this USB device to keystrokes?  Anyone heard of doing anything like this?

Thanks for any and all guidance on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Bome's midi translator can convert midi messages to key commands.

http://www.bome.com/products/miditranslator

They even have an APC40 demo on the site, though I have a feeling it's not to control WOW :)

Autohotkey can help you sequence key commands and macros that Bome's can't (that you then trigger with BOME), but it's Windoze. Sorry.

http://www.autohotkey.com/

I'm certain you can find a similar keybaord macro function for OsX.

Good luck.